# $n$ algebraically independent elements in a field of fractions implies $n$ algebraically independent elements in the $k$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-alegbra and $B$ be its field of fractions.  Suppose $\{\frac{f_{1}}{g_{1}},...,\frac{f_{n}}{g_{n}}\}$ is an algebraically independent set in B.  Question: Are there $n$ algebraically independent elements in A?

I can show that either $f_{i}$ or $g_{i}$ is algebraically independent for each of the fractions, using facts about field extensions.  So suppose each $f_{i}$ is algebraically independent in $A$.  Does this imply that $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$ is an algebraically independent set in $A$?  If not, how can I show that there are at least $n$ algebraically independent elements in A?  My two ideas are (1) use linear combinations of the $f_{i}$, and (2) successively choose different fractions in B that guarantee that $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$ is algebraically independent.  I am not sure how to go about proving that either of these two ways actually works.

I believe some of the comments of the following are relevant:
[Extension of residue fields and algebraic independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449500/extension-of-residue-fields-and-algebraic-independence?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T=\{f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_n\}$.  Replacing $A$ by $k[T]$ and $B$ by $k(T)$, we may assume $A$ is generated by $T$.

Now let $S\subseteq T$ be a maximal algebraically independent subset of $T$.  By maximality of $S$, every element of $T$ is algebraic over $k(S)$, and hence so is every element of $B$, since $B$ is generated by $T$ as a field extension of $k(S)$.  So $S$ is a transcendence basis for $B$ over $k$. But since $\{\frac{f_{1}}{g_{1}},...,\frac{f_{n}}{g_{n}}\}$ is algebraically independent, $B$ has transcendence degree at least $n$ over $k$.  It follows that $S$ has at least $n$ elements.

Comment: Why does k(T) being algebraic over k(S) imply S is a transcendence basis of B?

Comment: That's the definition of a transcendence basis?  An algebraically independent set over which the field is algebraic?

Comment: Suppose T is an algebraically independent subset of a field F/k such that F is not algebraic over k(T).  How does this imply that T can be extended to a larger algebraically independent set?

Comment: Take any element of $F$ which is not algebraic over $k(T)$, and add it to $T$.

Comment: Yeah I guess I answered my own question.

Comment: I would still be interested to know if the set mentioned in my question is algebraically independent.  It would be nice to have a more constructive (hence intuitive) proof.

Comment: I'm still skeptical: suppose F is algebraic over k(T) as before.  How do you know that T is maximal in F?  That's is, why can't there be a larger algebraically independent subset of F distinct from T?

Comment: What do you mean by "larger"?  "Maximal" just means "maximal with respect to inclusion".  It's a separate theorem that any two maximal algebraically independent subsets have the same cardinality.

Comment: It's certainly not true that if each $f_i$ is (on its own) algebraically independent over $k$, then the set of all of them is.  Consider $S=\{\frac{x}{y},\frac{x}{z}\}$ where $x,y,$ and $z$ are algebraically independent over $k$.

Comment: My question is how do you know T is maximal in F?  How does this follow from F being algebraic over k(T)?

Comment: If $T$ weren't maximal, there would be some element of $F$ you could add to it to get another algebraically independent set.  But then that element would be transcendental over $k(T)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77778/discussion-between-sihoashoihd-and-eric-wofsey).

Comment: Okay I see how your using the theorem that any two transcendence bases have the same cardinality now.